# Is there anything shared between MGO and MGSVTPP?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain, metal-gear-solid-5-online

In the past two days they opened MGO, and in some tooltips I saw something about resources shared between the multiplayer and the single player.

I am sure about the MB coin balance, and I know that the first character must be changed in the single player campaign, but are there other interactions like this?

Does progressing in the campaign/online bring some kind of bonus to the other part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, MB Coins and your avatar carry over to MGO, and these are the only things that do.

There are currently no bonus costumes or anything for progressing in the main story.